# Axis title with subscript but ignore second square bracket R

Tags: r, plot, ggpubr

I am trying to add a subscript to a ggpubr graph, which I found that I can do quite easily using `parse` and a set of square brackets. However, the problem is that within the axis label, I have a second set of square brackets that should be in regular type. Something like this:

```
library(ggpubr)
cars$speed <- log10(cars$speed)
ggscatter(cars, y = "speed", x = "dist", ylab = parse(text = "log[10](speed [μm])"))
```

[image: I want the base of the logarithm (10) in subscript, but not the distance measure]

I want the base of the logarithm (10) in subscript, but not the distance measure, [μm], which should keep it's brackets and stay in normal font size.

I have tried using `paste(parse(text = "log[10]"), "(speed [μm])")`, `parse(text = "log[10](speed \\[μm\\]")` and `expression`, but these have not worked for me so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively use `expression`...

```r
ggscatter(cars, y = "speed", x = "dist", ylab = expression(log[10]*"(speed [µm])"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```r
ggscatter(cars, y = "speed", x = "dist", ylab = 
            parse(text = "paste(log[10], \"(speed [μm])\")"))
```

[image]